# Subset of Rectangle Packing: minimize wasted space, fixed container size

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy, bin-packing

I am doing some research on a subset of the rectangle packing problem, and while I have found many similar problems discussed on SO, I do not see this specific problem.

Given the size of a container, and a set of rectangles, minimize the amount of wasted space. Multiple copies of the same rectangle can be added into the grid, but they are not allowed to rotate.

Example:

We are given a 5x5 grid to place squares into.

[image]

We are given the shapes of each piece:

- 4x1
- 1x3
- 4x2

[image]

To minimize the wasted space, we can place rectangles like so:

[image]

For a minimum wasted space of 2 squares.

**Although similar problems exist, has research been done on this subset of problem?**

**Does an algorithm exist for performing said task (or an approximation?)**

Similar problems:

[2D bin packing on a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918792/2d-bin-packing-on-a-grid)

The above link is useful but is a little too slow for my use cases.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_packing, the third problem type seems the same as this.

Comment: @RBarryYoung That looks like the right kind of problem, but Wikipedia doesn't really link any papers describing implementation, just time complexity. See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00373-007-0713-4

Comment: @PeterStenger maybe also add your timing data, and what "slow" is in your case, and the size of your the input in question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung's link shows the problem to be NP-hard, so it's extremely unlikely that any fast algorithm exists. I suggest consulting the 2 papers linked in the Wikipedia page. For a quick and dirty heuristic, I suggest simply greedily packing them down and to the left in random order; repeat with multiple different orders and choose the best.